# Handling multiple return values in javascript

Tags: javascript

Finally i'm writing a question on my own because i read other question here but still don't understand why my code doesn't work. Perhaps someone can explain me what i got wrong?

The Code runs till the search for the name "Joe", Then it say par2 is not defined...Why? In the check after the search function i can clearly see that both parameters par1 and par2 are returned...

```
var friends = {};
friends.bill = {
  firstName: "Bill",
  lastName: "Gates",
  number: "(206) 555-5555",
  address: ['One Microsoft Way', 'Redmond', 'WA', '98052']
};
friends.steve = {
  firstName: "Steve",
  lastName: "Jobs",
  number: "(408) 555-5555",
  address: ['1 Infinite Loop', 'Cupertino', 'CA', '95014']
};

function list(obj) {
  for (var prop in obj) {
    console.log(prop);
  }
};

function bettersearch(name2) {
  var sna = name2
  for (var prop in friends) {
    if (friends[prop].firstName === name2) {
      // console.log("Value found :",friends[prop]);
      return {
        par1: friends[prop],
        par2: sna
      }
    }
  }
};

// Test if the variables are returned
var test = bettersearch("Bill")
console.log("\n\n",test);
console.log("\n\n",test.par1);
console.log("\n\n",test.par2);


//Formatting function for a nice Output
function format(obj) {
  if (obj) {
    var result = "";
    result += "\nName:  " + obj.par1.firstName + " " + obj.lastName;
    result += "\nNumber:  " + obj.par1.number;
    result += "\nAddress: " + obj.par1.address.join(', ');
    console.log(result);
  } else {
    console.log("\nDer Name", obj.par2, "wurde nicht gefunden");
  }
}

//Call the functions
format(bettersearch("Bill"));
format(bettersearch("Steve"));
format(bettersearch("Joe"));
```

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When does the error occur? While in the `bettersearch` function or when you do the `format` on it?

Comment: Where is your "Joe" object in friends?

Comment: "Joe" does not exists in your friends list, so `bettersearch()` returns nothing with it. `format()` tries to access something that doesn't exist.

Comment: My Joe object shouldn't be there. In my Editor the code runs till the "else" part in the formatter function. Then it says there is no par2. I can't figure out whats wrong. looking at it for hours now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then it say par2 is not defined...

No, it doesn't. It says something like `Cannot convert 'obj' to object` or `Cannot access 'par2' on undefined`.

> Why?

Because your `bettersearch` function does not return *anything* when it doesn't find the name. In your `format` function you explicitly check for the existence of `obj`, but despite it being `undefined` you try to access `obj.par2`.

I think you are looking for

```
function bettersearch(name) {
  for (var prop in friends)
    if (friends[prop].firstName === name)
      return {
        friend: friends[prop],
        name: name
      };
  return {
    name: name
  }; // always return a result object
}

function format(obj) {
  if (obj.friend) {
    var result = "";
    result += "\nName:  " + obj.friend.firstName + " " + obj.friend.lastName;
    result += "\nNumber:  " + obj.friend.number;
    result += "\nAddress: " + obj.friend.address.join(', ');
    console.log(result);
  } else {
    console.log("\nDer Name", obj.name, "wurde nicht gefunden");
  }
}
```

Comment: Good catch, I didn't actually notice that until I read it in your answer.

Comment: Omg... you are totally right. it can't return an object if it does not access this part of the code...THX

Answer (score 1):

This might be a much better way to structure your data and write your `search` function

```
var friends = [
    {
      firstName: "Bill",
      lastName: "Gates",
      number: "(206) 555-5555",
      address: ['One Microsoft Way', 'Redmond', 'WA', '98052']
    },
    {
      firstName: "Steve",
      lastName: "Jobs",
      number: "(408) 555-5555",
      address: ['1 Infinite Loop', 'Cupertino', 'CA', '95014']
    }

];

function searchFriends(firstName) {
  return friends.filter(function(f) {
    return f.firstName === firstName;
  });
}
```

---

```
console.log(searchFriends("Bill"));
//=> [{"firstName":"Bill","lastName":"Gates","number":"(206) 555-5555","address":["One Microsoft Way","Redmond","WA","98052"]}]

console.log(searchFriends("Steve"));
//=> [{"firstName":"Steve","lastName":"Jobs","number":"(408) 555-5555","address":["1 Infinite Loop","Cupertino","CA","95014"]}]

console.log(searchFriends("Joe"));
//=> []
```

---

I make this suggestion because in your code, it'd be very easily to have duplicates.

E.g., what about `John Smith` and `John Smyth`? Both would use `friends.john`...

---

If you want the search result to return the query and the matches

```
function searchFriends(firstName) {
  return {
    search: firstName,
    result: friends.filter(function(f) {
      return f.firstName === firstName;
    })
  };
}
```

Use it the same way

```
console.log(searchFriends("Steve"));
// {
//   search: "Steve",
//   result: [{"firstName":"Steve","lastName":"Jobs","number":"(408) 555-5555","address":["1 Infinite Loop","Cupertino","CA","95014"]}]
// }

console.log(searchFriends("Joe"));
// {
//   search: "Joe",
//   result: []
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual error is

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'par2' of undefined

Your error is in your `console.log()` line where `if(obj)` returns false (meaning there is no object - it's actually *undefined*):

```
console.log("\nDer Name", obj.par2, "wurde nicht gefunden");
```

Remove that line altogether.

Comment: The error is in your `console.log()` line. You only need to remove that.